# How to use AQL functions inside user defined functions?

Tags: arangodb

Is it possible to use standard AQL functions inside a user-defined function ?

I tried to call `IS_IN_POLYGON()` inside a custom function and got this error at execution time :

```
Query: AQL: in function 'GEO::IS_IN_MULTIPOLYGON()': user function runtime error: ReferenceError: IS_IN_POLYGON is not defined at (…)
```

Is there any prefix / require() / anything, that should be used to access standard AQL functions ?

ArangoDB version : 3.2.4

Engine : RocksDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one can use AQL functions, including other UDFs, inside UDF functions.

Here is a complete example, using the AQL function `LENGTH()`:

```
aqlfunctions.register('TEST::test', function(collection) {
    'use strict';
    const db = require('@arangodb').db;
    const AQL_FUNCTION = db._query;
    return (typeof collection == "string") 
      ? AQL_QUERY('RETURN LENGTH(' + collection + ')').toArray()[0]
      : return typeof collection;
}, false);
```

To use a UDF function, simply include its namespace (e.g. `ARRAY::PRODUCT`) in the way you'd use in an AQL query.

*Caveat*: UDFs must be side-effect free.  They are not supposed to alter the database state in any way.

The ArangoDB documentation is not entirely clear what complications may arise if the return value of a UDF depends in any way on the database state (as in the above example).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.

One can use AQL functions inside a user defined function this way :
(example for fictitious `SOME_AQL_FUNCTION()` returning a boolean)

```
let result = AQL_QUERY("RETURN SOME_AQL_FUNCTION(…)").json[0];
```

Found that reading some test code on ArangoDB's GitHub.

Comment: They are simply [AQL function](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Functions/) calls in AQL queries. It does not make any difference whether it is in a user-defined function or not. The namespace of built-in functions is `_aql`, but does not need to be specified because it is the default namespace. Documented here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Extending/Conventions.html